# Rotate a position according to forward

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, raycasting

I am currently making a climbing detection system that follows the player around and detects the closest point the player can climb. I have a game object that casts rays according to the players position. The rays move with the player but do not rotate around. How can I make them rotate with the player ?

[image: Screenshot]

This is the code that draws the rays

```
void Update()
{
    //Debug.DrawRay();
    raySpace = surfaceWidth / definition;
    raySpaceDividedByTwo = raySpace / 2;
    surfaceWidthDividedByTwo = surfaceWidth / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < definition; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < definition; y++)
        {
            raycastCoordinates = new Vector3(
                (this.transform.position.x + (i * raySpace) + raySpaceDividedByTwo) - surfaceWidthDividedByTwo,
                 this.transform.position.y,
                (this.transform.position.z + (y * raySpace) + raySpaceDividedByTwo) - surfaceWidthDividedByTwo);

            //offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
            //raycastCoordinates = Quaternion.AngleAxis(this.transform.rotation.y, Vector3.up) * raycastCoordinates;

            raycastUpHitsList.Add(Physics.RaycastAll(raycastCoordinates, Vector3.up, detectionHeight, LayerMask.GetMask("Water")));
            Debug.DrawRay(raycastCoordinates, Vector3.up * detectionHeight, Color.green, 0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
void Update()
{
    //Debug.DrawRay();
    raySpace = surfaceWidth / definition;
    raySpaceDividedByTwo = raySpace / 2;
    surfaceWidthDividedByTwo = surfaceWidth / 2;

    for (int i = 0; i < definition; i++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < definition; y++)
        {
            raycastCoordinates = new Vector3(
                (this.transform.position.x + (i * raySpace) + raySpaceDividedByTwo) - surfaceWidthDividedByTwo,
                 this.transform.position.y,
                (this.transform.position.z + (y * raySpace) + raySpaceDividedByTwo) - surfaceWidthDividedByTwo) * transform.forward;//if this doesn't work, try transform.right instead

            //offset = Quaternion.AngleAxis(Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * turnSpeed, Vector3.up) * offset;
            //raycastCoordinates = Quaternion.AngleAxis(this.transform.rotation.y, Vector3.up) * raycastCoordinates;

            raycastUpHitsList.Add(Physics.RaycastAll(raycastCoordinates, Vector3.up, detectionHeight, LayerMask.GetMask("Water")));
            Debug.DrawRay(raycastCoordinates, Vector3.up * detectionHeight, Color.green, 0.1f);
        }
    }
}
```